# How can I return to the file that I'm editing when I execute it from inside Vim?

Tags: error, makeprg, make

Let's say that I have the following node.js script:

```
console.log("test")
```

If I use the command `:set makeprg=node\ % | set autowrite | make` I'll execute this node.js code and see the following result:

```
test

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

From now on, if I type `:make` I'll execute my node.js file from inside Vim. So far everything is fine... The problem begins when I have a mistake on my code, let's say my node.js file has the following content:

```
console.log("test")
fklsjfj
```

Well, `fklsjfj` is not a valid javascript command, so the execution of the file should break after reaching that line and printing what happened until there. However, when I try to execute this file from inside Vim I'll see the error message and end up on an empty screen, so the only way to go back to the file is closing it with `:q!` and opening it again. Why does this happen? Is there any way of going back to editing my file after executing a `node.js` code that contains an error?

Comment: I don't know if using `make` to execute your script is an ideal approach. Can't you run it with `:!`.... ?

Comment: @BLayer Ah yeah, you're right... I think I was overcomplicating the problem. Just using `:! node %` solved the issue for me. :)

Comment: Good to hear!  :)

Comment: Try `<C-l>` or `:redraw[!]`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble After using `:make` none of those commands are working too :/... The screen gets empty and I don't manage to go back to the file even if I try `:ls` and `:e myfile`... However, `:! node %` solved this issue already, it just shows the execution output and goes back to my file regardless if there are errors or not.

Comment: Huh. Could the node process be hung? I find it unlikely vim is hung, although either is possible. What about `<C-c>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that when you run `:make` and it fails, Vim tries to parse the output according to the [`'errorformat'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27errorformat%27) setting.

The output for the script with the syntax error looks something like this:

```
test
/path/to/script.js:2
fklsjfj
^

ReferenceError: fklsjfj is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/script.js:2:1)
```

But the default `'errorformat'` setting (mostly aimed at C compilers such as gcc) parses that output and thinks the error happened in a file named `"at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/script.js`. It tries to open that file, which doesn't actually exist, so it puts you in a new Vim buffer with that filename, and that's why it looks like you "lost" the file you're editing.

You can see that you're in a new buffer using the `:ls` command:

```
:ls
  1 #    "script.js"                         line 2
  2 %a   "at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/script.js" line 1
```

The buffer with the `%` flag is the current buffer, while the buffer with the `#` flag is your original script.

You can go back to your script with `:e#`, possibly followed by `:bd#` to delete the bogus buffer (you don't really need to, but you might as well.)

A more proper and permanent solution to this problem would be to set `'errorformat'` appropriately, so that when you're using `node %` as a `'makeprg'` to run your JavaScript code and there's an error, it will properly parse the output format of the output to correctly populate the quickfix list with the errors and move you to the actual file (and line) from where the first error happened.

You can find a Vim plug-in that sets that up in [felixge/vim-nodejs-errorformat](https://github.com/felixge/vim-nodejs-errorformat), which you can configure using vim-plug or native Vim packages or whatever other Vim plug-in manager you're using. Note that this plug-in will also already set up `'makeprg'` to run `'node %'`, so it takes care of that part as well.

Note that the script will set up this particular `'makeprg'` and `'errorformat'` for *every* JavaScript file you open in Vim (any file detected as filetype `javascript`), which might not be the best approach overall... (Other plug-ins will typically configure `:make` to run something like `eslint` or use the npm package definition in a JavaScript/NodeJS project.) But perhaps this setup suits your use case well and might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I’m not sure this is the issue: see the comment after my redraw suggestion.

Comment: @Ben I reproduced it locally and that's what I saw... It looks puzzling (without a statusline) but I was editing a file with a garbled name like that. `:ls` confirmed it and `:e#` got me back to my script.

Comment: I didn't really try the plug-in first-hand, but if it does what it claims (README is pretty detailed, with example) then I assume it would fix that exact issue.

Comment: Hmm though now I see raylight's comment talking about `:ls` and `:e myfile` too, so not so sure what's happening with their setup...

Comment: I wonder how `:q!` will work but other commands such as `:ls` apparently won't...

Comment: Very odd indeed…

Comment: Re: the plugin, Aside from the autocommand to finangle certain quickfix results (which is installed globally? yuck), the whole thing could have been a `:compiler` script

Comment: @Ben, totally agreed. That's what I wanted to convey in the last paragraph (without going into all the details of what a `:compiler` is.) In any case, I think `'errorformat'` is still at least part of the issue. (It would be nice if raylight could check and confirm that...)

Comment: My mistake, I did some experiments here and my comment about trying `:e myfile` was actually wrong... What I really tried was `:e number` like in `:e 1`. That was wrong, the way of moving around files from their numbers id is `:b number`. So using both `:e myfile` or `:b 1` worked fine to going back to the original file...